# App crashes when deserializing JSON array of objects without name

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on a `ListView` which is showing several processes of our system. The system unfortunatedly only provide the json in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "f1": "w1",
        "date": "2018.11.09"        
    },
    {
        "f1": "w2",
        "date": "2018.11.09"
    }
]
```

My app crashes if it starts the deserialization and I think the reason is, that the object has no "description". But how do I solve this?

this is my code for downloading and deserialize the json:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;                       
    json = client.DownloadString("http://x.x.x.x/test.json");
}
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Query>(json);
```

Query:

```
public class Query
{
    public List<Process> Processes { get; set; }
}
```

Process:

```
public class Process
{
    [JsonProperty("f1")]
    public string f1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us `Query` please

Comment: try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Process>>(json);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because JSON is trying to deserialise your values into a 'Query' object as specified:

```
{
    "processes" : []
}
```

When the result is a List, change the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Query>` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Process>>`, and see if that helps :).

Comment: Good. Samething I've answered in the question as a comment.